# How to calculate $\lim_{x\to a}{x^n - a^n \over x - a}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

I've been trying to prove this with L'Hôpital's rule because my teachers asked me that... but I don't know how. It may be really easy to do but I can't find the way. Can someone explain this to me? Thank you.

Comment: [Here's a tutorial in MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Without L'Hospital rule $$\lim _{ x\rightarrow a }{ \frac { { x }^{ n }-{ a }^{ n } }{ x-a }  } =\lim _{ x\rightarrow a }{ \frac { \left( x-a \right) \left( \overset { n\quad terms }{ \overbrace { { x }^{ n-1 }+{ x }^{ n-2 }a+...+{ a }^{ n-1 } }  }  \right)  }{ x-a }  } =n{ a }^{ n-1 }$$

Answer (score 4):

Let $f(x)=x^n$ so $f'(x)=n x^{n-1}$. Then the limit is by definition $f'(a)=n a^{n-1}$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\frac{x^n-a^n}{x-a}=\lim_{x \rightarrow a}nx^{n-1}=na^{n-1}$$

Alternatively, if you take $f(x)=x^n$. Then you simply want to calculate $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$ which is equal to $f'(a)$.

Comment: Missing $ at end of first line (tried to edit but ran into the annoying 6-char limit).